# Why doesn't jvisualvm see my Play Framework app?

Tags: java, playframework, jmx, jvisualvm

I'm trying to use jvisualvm to peer into a Play Framework app.

**Environment**: Windows 7 bit, Java 7 64 bit.

**Step**:

1) Added `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote` to `_JAVA_OPTIONS` enviornment variable.

[Play Output](https://gist.github.com/3070945)

> Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xms800m -Xmx1500m -XX:PermSize=64m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dcom.sun.manageme nt.jmxremote

2) Ran jvisual vm (from `C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_03\bin`).

3) I am not seeing the Play process among the list of local processes.

What am I missing?

Comment: You're probably seeing the JVM that Play is running on, not Play itself.  Figure out which PID is associated with Play and see if that helps.

Comment: In the output you provided you can see: `pid is 8244` - are you sure there is no such process in the list?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz - I am sure.

Comment: @duffymo - I am not seeing that JVM. I see only two JVMs: IntelliJ and VisualVM itself.

Answer (score 4):

My environment

- Developer PC: Windows 8, VisualVM in JDK1.6
- Server: Ubuntu, JDK1.6, play 1.2.2

For connecting to local Play app, the only option **"-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote"** is OK.

But for connecting to remote Play app, more options are needed for JVM.

Since set **_JAVA_OPTIONS** environment will affect all Java programs, I changed play starting script: **framework/pym/play/application.py**

```
def java_cmd(self, java_args, cp_args=None, className='play.server.Server', args = None):
  ...
  java_args.append('-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote')
  java_args.append('-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=5678')
  java_args.append('-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false')
  java_args.append('-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false')
  java_args.append('-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false')
  java_args.append('-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.0.10')

  java_cmd = [self.java_path(), '-javaagent:%s' % self.agent_path()] + java_args + ['-classpath', cp_args, '-Dapplication.path=%s' % self.path, '-Dplay.id=%s' % self.play_env["id"], className] + args
  return java_cmd
```

Then restart Play app, and reconnect it from VisualVM.

Answer (score 4):

There was a bug that prevented processes from showing up in jvisualvm (or jps) if they specified a java.io.tmpdir. See https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7009828.

Also, setting com.sun.management.jmxremote hasn't been necessary since Java 6 (at least not to connect to a process on the same machine). See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html.